# Sequelize get parent reference when multiple child objects are created

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm creating a set of Sequelize model as a chain below. After creating all child models and if it is a success I want to redirect it to the detail page of the parent (Invoice). The problem is since I'm using a loop in how can I know all the children are created correctly to do a redirection? In the redirect code, I want to access parent id as well.

```
Invoice.create({
    //set parent properties
}).then(invoice => { //update company id
    return Company.findOne({where: {id: id}}).then(company => {
        //console.log('setting the company...')
        return invoice.setCompany(company).then(invoice => {return invoice})
    })
}).then(invoice => { //create order items
    orderItems.each((i, v) => {
        invoice.createOrderItem({
        }).then(orderItem => {
            return Product.findOne({where: {id: v.companyId).then(product => {
                //console.log('setting the product...')
                return orderItem.setProduct(product).then(orderItem => {return orderItem})                       
            })
        }).then(orderItem => {
            return Unit.findOne({where: {id: v.unitId}).then(unit => {
                //console.log('setting the unit...')
                return orderItem.setUnit(unit).then(orderItem => {return invoice})
            })
        }).then(invoice => {
            //console.log('returning invoice: ' + invoice)
            return invoice
        }).catch(errOI => {
            console.log('Error while creating order items: ' + errOI)
        })
    })
}).then(invoice => {
    //redirect to detail page
    console.log('I: ' + invoice)
}).catch(errI => {
    console.log('Error while creating invoice: ' + errI)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Promise method, it is resolve once the children records are created.
2. Loop the orderItems and call the Promise method,
3. Use Promise.all to resolve all the Promises.

```
function createChild(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        invoice.createOrderItem({})
        .then(orderItem => {
            return Product.findOne({where: {id: v.companyId).then(product => {
                //console.log('setting the product...')
                return orderItem.setProduct(product).then(orderItem => {return orderItem})                       
            })
        })
        .then(orderItem => {
            return Unit.findOne({where: {id: v.unitId}).then(unit => {
                //console.log('setting the unit...')
                return orderItem.setUnit(unit).then(orderItem => {return invoice})
            })
        })
        .then(invoice => {
            //console.log('returning invoice: ' + invoice)
            return invoice;
        })
        .then(invoice => {
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(errOI => {
            console.log('Error while creating order items: ' + errOI)
            reject();
        })
    });
}

Invoice.create({
    //set parent properties
}).then(invoice => { //update company id
    return Company.findOne({where: {id: id}}).then(company => {
        //console.log('setting the company...')
        return invoice.setCompany(company).then(invoice => {return invoice})
    })
}).then(invoice => { //create order items
    return orderItems.map(v => {
        return createChild(v);
    })
}).then(promises => {
    return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(done => {
        // direct the page
    })
})
}).catch(errI => {
    console.log('Error while creating invoice: ' + errI)
})
```

Comment: Here `}).then(promises => {
    return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(done => {
        // direct the page
    })
})` receives the array element. Not the promise.